# Unable to pass PSObject as an argument to to Start-Process

Tags: powershell, start-process, psobject

I had a requirement to read an input file, which is an xml (as below)

```
<Parent>
  <Child>
    <grandchilditem1>Server1</grandchilditem1>
    <grandchilditem2>Database1</grandchilditem2>
  </Child>
</Parent>
<Parent>
  <Child>
    <grandchilditem1>Server1</grandchilditem1>
    <grandchilditem2>Database1</grandchilditem2>
  </Child>
</Parent>
```

My main powershell script parses the xml, and creates an object with input parameters in a foreach loop for each Child and calls another powershell script with the argument as that object created from each child item. This is necessary as to run scripts in parallel in different consoles.

```
$Child.ChildNodes.GetEnumerator()|ForEach-Object{
  $InputOBJ = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        Server = $_.grandchilditem1
        Database = $_.grandchilditem2
    }
  $psfilepath = Get-Location
  Start-Process -filepath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList @("-NoExit", "$psfilepath\ls.ps1 $InputOBJ") -WindowStyle Normal
}
```

My problem is, this executes fine and opens two different consoles for 2 child nodes, but the $inputobj isn't passing completely. It gets truncated. However, if I pass each individual parameter as a string value, it accepts all.

I want to know, what is the reason that an object isn't properly passing.

In the new console that opens, the output will be only the first item. 
for eg., my ls.ps1 has a statement

```
write-host $inputobj
```

it outputs, just this.

@{Server=Server1;

The object structure is compromised too. I believe, its being sent as a string instead of an object.

Please let me know if anybody had more knowledge on this.

Comment: Yes, process arguments are strings only. You may want to look into using jobs via Start-Job & Receive-Job rather than starting a whole new process. I believe that objects are serialized across job boundaries so it should handle hashtables and simple custom objects relatively well.

Comment: Thanks Mike for the clarification. However, there is a nice log being displayed on the new console that opens up. Start-Job would run it background, and I am not sure, if there is a way to track progress of all the background running jobs. Good idea though, I will explore this option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can only pass strings to [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process?view=powershell-6) an alternative is to serialise the object to xml using [Export-Clixml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-6), pass the path to the serialised object, then in your target script deserialise the object using [Import-Clixml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-clixml?view=powershell-6).

Your main script will look something like this:

```
$tempObjectPath = [System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()
Export-Clixml -InputObject $InputOBJ -Path $tempObjectPath

$psfilepath = Get-Location
Start-Process `
    -filepath "powershell.exe" `
    -ArgumentList @("-NoExit", "$psfilepath\ls.ps1 $tempObjectPath") `
    -WindowStyle Normal
```

Then in your target script, deserialise the xml back to your PSObject:

```
$InputOBJ = Import-Clixml -Path $tempObjectPath

# Optionally, delete the temporary file
Remove-Item -Path $tempObjectPath -Force
```